# How to change background of Spinner drop down window?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I set custom `layout_dropdown_menu_popup_item` with dark background but still there is white color at the top and bottom of popup window

[image]

```
val adapterCity = ArrayAdapter<String>(
    activityContext,
    R.layout.layout_dropdown_menu_popup_item,
    listOf("New York", "Las Vegas")
)
binding.citySpinner.setAdapter(adapterCity)
```

R.layout.layout_dropdown_menu_popup_item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorBackgroundSecond"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceSubtitle1" />
```

Comment: Can you add `@style/PrimaryText`?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman we don't need it, I've edited the question and removed it

Comment: Actually it works fine in my case

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman I don't think so